# Not able to get name/value pairs from JSON object, when using variable

Tags: android, json

Not able to get name/value pairs from JSON object, when using the variable but able to read it  when hard coding the name.

To better explain :

1) My JSON object is like this - 
                                  {.....
                                    { "rates":{ "name1": value1, "name2": value2 ...etc }
                                 ...}

2) I am able to read this object in my android app.

3) Now this rate object name value pairs, i am trying to read based on user input -

```
          String s1 = '"'+name1+'"';  // here name1 i got from user input, & converted into string
```

4) Now when i am trying to get the value from rates object, i am getting null exception -

```
            JSONObject rateObject = jObject.getJSONObject("rates");  //able to get  
                                                                    complete object

            String rate1 = (String) rateObject.get(s1); // giving NULL exception
```

5) But if i use hard code string, it works -

```
            String rate1 = (String) rateObject.get("name1"); // working
```

Any pointers why its not working while using variable.

thanks

---

Thanks for suggestions, i sorted out the problem. There are 2 mistakes i was doing - 1) Using the quotes as correctly pointed out by others and 2) casting the double value to string. Correcting both has resolved my problem :)

Comment: Show the code where name1 was assigned to user input value.

Comment: Whatever the value of `name1` is, `s1` is a string whose _contents_ begin and end with a double-quote character. There is no field with that as a name in your JSON input -- if there were it would have to be encoded as `..., "\"name1\"": value1, ...`.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of your final code snippet, you are *actually* doing

```
String rate1 = (String) rateObject.get("\"name1\""); //note the extra quotes
```

because you have bookended the user input string with double-quote characters. You just want the input string itself with no bookending. The quotes in the JSON notation serve to delineate each key name; the quotes are not part of the key name itself.

You need to omit the quotes when you create `s1`:

```
String s1 = name1;
```

Or, if `name1` is not a String already:

```
String s1 = name1.toString();
```

Comment: Actually i have initally tried with this way only by not using the quotes, but i was getting the NULL exception so thought to add quotes to string, in order to make it work. But no avail :(

Comment: Thanks i sorted out the problem. There are 2 mistakes i was doing - 1) Using the quotes as correctly pointed out by others and 2) casting the double value to string. Correcting both has resolved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
String s1 = '"'+name1+'"';
```

with:

```
String s1 = name1;
```

Comment: Actually i have initally tried with this way only by not using the quotes, but i was getting the NULL exception so thought to add quotes to string, in order to make it work. But no avail :(

Comment: It sounds like you're not assigning name1 to anything. At some point in your code, name1 needs to be assigned to a String with contents "name1".